# Ngnix Seperation Of SubFolder Sites

Tags: nginx

So let's say I have a site at example.com.

I would like to setup another site at example.com/somewhere else.

Can Ngnix be configured so these sites are not connected in anyway?  Meaning, a session variable started on /somewhere can't be seen on example.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I presume it's valid to ask how nginx can help here, this matter is ultimately influenced by the web-browser, too, and is outside of nginx' domain.

There is no way to prevent an app at `example.com/somewhere` from setting cookies for `example.com/`.  Sure, you could potentially block certain `Set-Cookie` directives through nginx or another web-server, but the app could still use JavaScript for setting such cookies.

Using distinct domain names is the only way to achieve separation between the two apps.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15939/does-setting-the-cookie-path-protect-me-from-xss-from-another-context/32698#32698.

Comment: Thannks for the info!